# Show isomorphism in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T : $M_{2x2} \rightarrow M_{2x2}$ be defined by

T(A) = $\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0          \\[0.3em]
       1 & 0         \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix} A$

Is T one-to-one? Show R(T) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Clearly, T is not one-to-one as there is not a unique solution to the linear transformation. However, how can I show that R(T) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$? The only thing that sticks out to me is that the dimensions of R(T) and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equal.

Comment: Do you know that finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension?

Comment: @Nameless I do now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0   \\
       1 & 0   \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
       x & y   \\
       z & t    \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
       x & y    \\
       x & y    \\
\end{bmatrix}\to (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$$

Comment: Right, and now I can use the fact that these two vector spaces have the same dimension and are therefore isomorphic.

Comment: @ChrisD, no need to use that fact: you've given an explicit isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The image of $T$ is the set of matrices of the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
       a & b \\
       a & b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so clearly has dimension $2$.